# java regex extract information out of brackets

Tags: java, regex, brackets

i cant figure out how i manage to solve the problem of getting information out of square brackets as well as the normal ones. I want the content of them both.
i tried:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]]*\\]"); 
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\[|\\([^\\)]*|[^\\]]*\\]|\\)"); 
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\[|\\([^{\\]|\\)}]*\\]|\\)");
```

p works perfectly for the squared ones only and then i tried to add the normal braces, but no success. 
 a sample of a string would be

```
"(info1) something-uninteresting [info2] s.u. [info3] s.u. (info4)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[\\[(][^\\])]*[\\])]
```

Comment: it only gets the squared ones again

Comment: now its perfect thanks alot, although i dont quiet get it, why this works ... to be precise: what does the first occuring ] mean ? okok ok now i got it :)

Comment: Yeah, regex that will find also `(xx]` :D. Anyway OP will not probably have such cases so it will do the trick. +1

Comment: @Pshemo You are totally correct, but it seems not very likely he will encounter such cases although I could have built a more robust one using a combination of back references and balancing-group definitions. Anyway Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(\\(.*?\\)|\\[.*?\\])*?
```

Comment: eclipse says that this is not valid at all

Comment: @user2664856 Because you need to double escape the backslashes in Java.

Comment: that is true, I'm sorry

Comment: @TJamesBoone Almost, you only did 1 slash on the first two, has to be 2 each as well

Comment: I am sorry, I did a derp, fixed it based on the comments, sorry guys :(

Comment: there is still something wrong i quess, my code will run endlessly with this pattern

Comment: Why do you need `*` at the end?

Comment: It depends on the loop you use it in, I have made it less greedy to make it more suitable for you

Comment: @pshemo Because there are multiple occurrences

Comment: @Voidpaw but using `matcher.find()` we are able to find them one-by-one

Comment: @Pshemo but running the proper regex finds them all at the same time, it saves you code execution

Comment: i dont actually understand what loop you mean, but thanks for effort, as the question is already answered its not too important

Comment: @Voidpaw nope, using `*` you are saying zero or more, so it will find also empty spaces between each character that is outside of bracket. Best choice would be removing `*?` from your regex. Or if you believe there is purpose of it include working code that will use this regex.